# What conditions will trigger XPM to indicate that the preview is out of date?

Tags: experience-manager

It seems to be a "classic symptom" of a mis-configured Experience manager that the Update button gets a yellow icon, and you see the message "The preview for this page is not up to date".

As an aid to trouble-shooting such problems, I'd like a better understanding of what normally triggers this message in a well-configured system. What makes XPM 'think' that the preview is out of date? How does it know?

In particular, I'd be interested to know why it would think that a freshly loaded page was out of date, even before you've edited anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some or all of the following may apply:

- Incorrect XPM markup
- Output/web app caching means that the latest published content is not being shown
- Misconfigured Tridion caching means cached content is not being invalidated on republish

Lastly but not least:

The content on the page might actually not be up to date (eg component/page has been modified since the page was last published) - it gives you the alert and the option to do a preview update to see the page with the latest CM content. Like Bart mentions, its quite common to see this when you have dynamic content on the page, as publishing the page may not publish *all* elements on the page. The annoying thing about these situations, is that hitting Update Preview, might not actually solve the problem - I think it just publishes the page, and not dynamic components added to the page by a query (not 100% sure of this however - it needs to be tested)

Also good to know is that Fast Track Publishing via the oData Preview webservice does not do any resolving, so if you rely on a custom resolver to manage the items that need to be published for a page content update, you will not see this behaviour happening with Session Preview updates.

Comment: No resolving and [no deployment](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/374/46) either. :-)

Comment: Adding to the comment on dynamic elements: headers and footers (i.e. in the DXA example site) can cause the same issue: updating the page preview does not update the header and footer and old content in the header or foorter can trigger the "The preview for this page is not up to date" message.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about all of the triggers, but certainly the case of what you are describing it will be comparing the information in the XPM comments vs. what is in the CMS.

So assuming you are using the XPM comment style, your published page would have something like this:

```xml
...
  <div>
  <!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID":"tcm:1-2", 
                                      "ComponentModified":"2014-12-08T10:09:34", 
                                      "ComponentTemplateID":"tcm:1-3-32", 
                                      "ComponentTemplateModified":"2014-07-29T13:16:22", 
                                      "IsRepositoryPublished":false} -->
  ...
  </div>
<!-- Page Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:1-4-64",
                     "PageModified":"2014-10-31T12:32:31",
                     "PageTemplateID":"tcm:1-5-128",
                     "PageTemplateModified":"2014-06-25T14:37:12"} -->
...
</body>
```

Now if in the CMS either your Page, Page Template, Component or Component Template would have a different modified date than what is mentioned in the XPM comments on the published page, this will trigger the preview is not up to date.

When your published page contains the old SiteEdit comment style (that still works), then it would have a version number for each of the items, rather than a modified date. But again if what is on the Page doesn't match with what is in the CMS, you are indicated your page is out of date.

Another thing which can be an influence is when you have DCPs on the Page, which are dynamically rendered (so not actually on the Page in the CMS, but rendered via a query at request time). If these are correctly marked they should not have an influence, unless their dates/versions don't match with what is in the CMS. When not marked as `IsQueryBased` it could also trigger the page being out of date.

Answer (score 4):

The XPM ComponenPresentation tag (HTML comment) contains the modified date of the Component. XPM is comparing the value  on the page with the last modified date of the Component in CM. Based on that, it will notify the user that there is a new version available.